# How to change Dates in HTML Table cells to Local Time with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, html-table

I'm not good in JavaScript.  Here is my html "Event Table" below with Date and Event Name:

```
<table id="events">
    <tr>
        <td>23 Aug 20:00</td>
        <td>Event 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>23 Aug 18:30</td>
        <td>Event 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>23 Aug 17:00</td>
        <td>Event 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>22 Aug 13:45</td>
        <td>Event 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Event 1</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Dates are in GMT +2. I would like that these Event Dates be automatically converted to user's local time. Better if it is possible with "foreach", because the table consists of many rows.

Solved, thanks to Answers, but maybe there is a more elegant way?

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<table id="events">
    <tr>
        <td><script>var date1 = moment('23 Aug 20:00', 'D MMM HH:mm').utc();
document.write(date1.format('D MMM HH:mm'));</script></td>
        <td>Event 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><script>var date1 = moment('23 Aug 18:30', 'D MMM HH:mm').utc();
document.write(date1.format('D MMM HH:mm'));</script></td>
        <td>Event 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><script>var date1 = moment('23 Aug 17:00', 'D MMM HH:mm').utc();
document.write(date1.format('D MMM HH:mm'));</script></td>
        <td>Event 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><script>var date1 = moment('22 Aug 13:45', 'D MMM HH:mm').utc();
document.write(date1.format('D MMM HH:mm'));</script></td>
        <td>Event 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><script>var date1 = moment('22 Aug 11:30', 'D MMM HH:mm').utc();
document.write(date1.format('D MMM HH:mm'));</script></td>
        <td>Event 1</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried and what the problem is? Sounds like you need to use the Date functions of Javascript.

Comment: I have no Idea, yet. Only got the Time script, that shows user's local time:

Comment: Never post code in comments. It's not readable. Please edit it into your question and explain what you've already tried. You'll get the best help that way. Thanks.

Comment: This code has no sense without a function declaration or something. I'll add it to question. My recomendation is to modify the `document.write(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use moment library to format and automatically convert dates to user's local time

```js
// here array with timestamps, most developers save dates in this format in database
var eventsDate = [
  1503576747,
  1491998594,
  1482819432,
  1481177832,
  1415463675
];

// function which render table
var renderEventsTable = function() {

  var tableContainer = document.getElementById('tableContainer');
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tbody = '';

  table.setAttribute("id", "events");
  table.setAttribute("class", "table");
  
  eventsDate.forEach(function(date, i) {
    tbody += '<tr>' +
               '<td>' + moment(date).format('DD MMMM hh:mm') + '</td>' + 
               '<td>Event ' + i + '</td>' +
             '</tr>'
  });

  table.innerHTML = tbody;
  tableContainer.appendChild(table);
};

// the table will render when the page loads
window.onload = function() {
  renderEventsTable();
}
```

```css
table {  
    color: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    border-spacing: 0; 
}

td {  
    border: 1px solid #000; /* No more visible border */
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tableContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! It is still of great help in 2023.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Add the script to your page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js"></script>
```

Use the following to change the time format to user's current locale:

```
var localTime = moment('your date').utc();
```